# UDIM tile shifting automation / tool

Tags: uv, texture-coordinates

There is a topic [here](http://polycount.com/discussion/128895/knald-master-thread/p15) which describes how to shift UDIMs and create different meshes from it from Knald (which currently lacks UDIM support).

The Blender thread starts at the line:

> Sure, the thing to remember is that Knald can only see the UVs that are within the 1001 area

Since the described process is time-consuming if you have many models, I was hoping for an automated solution.

Does such a solution exist? I have like 100 models, so an automated process would be really helpful.